# Selector nth-child giving unexpected output

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Im trying to get the first `span` inside each div with `class g-b`:

```
<div class="g-b">
    <div class="g-b">
        <span> $219.99 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        List price:
        <span> $329.99 </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="g-b">
    <span> $39.99 </span>
</div>
```

As you can see there are two divs with `class g-b`, there `first span child` has the text: "$219.99" and "$39.99". So using Jquery to get them:

```
var t = $('.g-b span:nth-child(1)').text();
alert(t);
```

This is giving me all the prices instead of just the ones in the first span of `g-b`. How is that possible? What should I do to get the first span in all the divs with `class g-b`?

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dpdM/5/)

ps I dont want to use Jquery `each()` or some fancy Javascript`(i++)` coding, Im just looking for an elegant CSS like selector for Jquery, `:eq()` is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your HTML, the behaviour you have reported is correct. The first 2 prices are both inside a container with class `g-b`, that's why you get all the prices. To fix, use `>`

```
$('.g-b > span:nth-child(1)')
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dpdM/6/

This way you will get all the first children of any `.g-b > span`.

If you want to get only the first one, use `:eq()`

```
$('.g-b > span:eq(0)')
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dpdM/11/

Answer (score 2):

For the first element you can simply use the first selector like so:

```
var t = $('.g-b span:first').text();
```

Also, `nth` implies you want to iterate through a given set of elements, but you only want every first occurance. `nth` is useful for problems like "give me every second/third/fourth/nth element you find". If you want one element, use `:eq(index)` or :first  (:first equals `:eq(0)` )if its the first.

Comment: nth is not zero based

Comment: By the way, BeNdErR's answer works for you but it really is not best practice. Actually you would use a foreach here to add all the values to the string. Doing it with :eq or :last will only consider the last element found and not combine them

Answer (score 1):

**Try this** - Just edited your code only , Check whether it is fine for you

```
 var t = $('div div:first-child span:first-child').text();
 alert(t);
```